# Setting default parameter/style for new layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

For each new layer I create in QGIS, I have to set the style parameters again.

Can I set the default parameters for each new layer?

Answer (score 6):

Yes !!!
It is located in the "Project Properties" dialog.

Look for the tab `Default styles`
[image: ![Default Style Tab]

You can even define macros to be executed by default
(For more see [QGIS Manual](http://documentation.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#project-properties))

[image: Projet Properties window]

Comment: Minor but I was expecting a screenshot of `Default styles`, normal it's `Macros` screenshot instead (although you mentioned them just after)?

Comment: new screenshot added

Comment: Can you "copy" an existing style and "paste" it as the default, as you can between layers? Would be cool if you could.

Comment: @WesleyKitlasten:   Yes. It in the contextual menu (right-Click) of layer you can "Copy style". And after selecting a layer you can right-click and paste the format

Comment: @kFly, but can you set it as the default, so every layer you add gets that style by default, rather than something that appears to be somewhat random? Also, it would be nice if "copy" and "paste" for styles were no located 3 submenus deep!!